# Recommendations of Python REST (web services) framework?

Tags: python, web-services, rest, frameworks

Is there a list somewhere of recommendations of different Python-based REST frameworks for use on the serverside to write your own RESTful APIs? Preferably with pros and cons.

Please feel free to add recommendations here. :)

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on using web.py http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/blog/blog.php?/archives/6-Create-a-simple-REST-web-service-with-Python.html

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Something to be careful about when designing a RESTful API is the conflation of GET and POST, as if they were the same thing. It's easy to make this mistake with [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)'s [function-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/) and [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/)'s default dispatcher, although both frameworks now provide a way around this problem ([class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) and [MethodDispatcher](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cpdispatch.html#cherrypy._cpdispatch.MethodDispatcher), respectively).

[HTTP-verbs are very important](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services) in REST, and unless you're very careful about this, you'll end up falling into a [REST anti-pattern](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-anti-patterns).

Some frameworks that get it right are [web.py](http://webpy.org/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) and [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org). When combined with the [mimerender](https://github.com/martinblech/mimerender) library (full disclosure: I wrote it), they allow you to write nice RESTful webservices:

```
import web
import json
from mimerender import mimerender

render_xml = lambda message: '<message>%s</message>'%message
render_json = lambda **args: json.dumps(args)
render_html = lambda message: '<html><body>%s</body></html>'%message
render_txt = lambda message: message

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'greet'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class greet:
    @mimerender(
        default = 'html',
        html = render_html,
        xml  = render_xml,
        json = render_json,
        txt  = render_txt
    )
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'world'
        return {'message': 'Hello, ' + name + '!'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The service's logic is implemented only once, and the correct representation selection (Accept header) + dispatch to the proper render function (or template) is done in a tidy, transparent way.

```
$ curl localhost:8080/x
<html><body>Hello, x!</body></html>

$ curl -H "Accept: application/html" localhost:8080/x
<html><body>Hello, x!</body></html>

$ curl -H "Accept: application/xml" localhost:8080/x
<message>Hello, x!</message>

$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" localhost:8080/x
{'message':'Hello, x!'}

$ curl -H "Accept: text/plain" localhost:8080/x
Hello, x!
```

**Update (April 2012)**: added information about Django's class-based views, CherryPy's MethodDispatcher and Flask and Bottle frameworks. Neither existed back when the question was asked.

Comment: This is incorrect, Django has full support for recognizing POST vs GET and limiting views to only certain methods.

Comment: I meant that, by default, Django treats POST and GET as if they were the same thing, which is very inconvenient when you are doing RESTful services as it forces you to do:

    if request.method == 'GET':
        do_something()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        do_something_else()

web.py doesn't have that problem

Comment: @Wahnfrieden: If there is native support in Django for handling different HTTP verbs separately (by "native" I mean not needing "if request.method==X"), could you please point me to some documentation?

Comment: The conflation of POST and GET does not apply to Django's Class Based Views (added in 1.3), but I believe is valid for the earlier releases.

Comment: Answer is incorrect about CherryPy. From Docs: "REST (Representational State Transfer) is an architectural style that is well-suited to implementation in CherryPy." - http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/progguide/REST.html

Comment: Django's class-based views which were introduced in 1.3 deal with method differentiation well.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: got it, I have updated the answer to reflect this new feature.

Comment: @MartinBlech would you mine updating this example so it works with your latest from Git?

Comment: @MartinBlech I can't get it to work either. Adding `@mimerender (...` gives me `mimerender is not callable`

Answer (score 70):

Surprised no one mentioned [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Many of the top answers to this question provide examples.  An example would be nice for this answer.

Comment: Can you decouple the route configuration ('/') from the function like in web.py?

Comment: Yes, you can decouple them: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule

Comment: Flask wasn't out there when the question was asked...

Comment: **Flask doesn't work with Python 3.x**

Comment: Flask.dev now supports Python 3

Comment: Flask [supports Python 3.3](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/python3/) or higher.

Comment: I had to create a complete REST API in a single night for a project I was working on after already working a full day at my job. I went with Flask after reading this question and finding [this article](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) and was able to knock it out of the park while still getting a full night's sleep once I was done. Thank you.

Comment: noob here, how this is a RESTful?

Comment: Check out http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ for a Flask plugin to help with implementing a REST API in Flask.

Answer (score 23):

We're using [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) for RESTful web services.

Note that -- out of the box -- Django did not have fine-grained enough authentication for our needs.  We used the [Django-REST interface](http://code.google.com/p/django-rest-interface/), which helped a lot.  [We've since rolled our own because we'd made so many extensions that it had become a maintenance nightmare.]

We have two kinds of URL's: "html" URL's which implement the human-oriented HTML pages, and "json" URL's which implement the web-services oriented processing.  Our view functions often look like this.

```
def someUsefulThing( request, object_id ):
    # do some processing
    return { a dictionary with results }

def htmlView( request, object_id ):
    d = someUsefulThing( request, object_id )
    render_to_response( 'template.html', d, ... )

def jsonView( request, object_id ):
    d = someUsefulThing( request, object_id )
    data = serializers.serialize( 'json', d['object'], fields=EXPOSED_FIELDS )
    response = HttpResponse( data, status=200, content_type='application/json' )
    response['Location']= reverse( 'some.path.to.this.view', kwargs={...} )
    return response
```

The point being that the useful functionality is factored out of the two presentations.  The JSON presentation is usually just one object that was requested.  The HTML presentation often includes all kinds of navigation aids and other contextual clues that help people be productive.

The `jsonView` functions are all very similar, which can be a bit annoying.  But it's Python, so make them part of a callable class or write decorators if it helps.

Comment: I separated my rest-api into a different app (in django settings INSTALLED_APPS). Keeps you from having to do this weird view naming...

Comment: Awful repetition of d = someUsefulThing... Even Django guys suggest DRY.

Comment: @temoto: If `y = someUsefulThing(...)` is an "Awful repetition", then all references to all functions and methods is "awful".  I fail to understand how to avoid **referencing** a function more than once.

Comment: Please, be fair. I wasn't talking about function reference only. I quoted the statement, which includes expression which includes arguments. When you need to change arguments passed to someUsefulThing, there's a chance that one forgets to do so in all calls.

Comment: @temoto: "When you need to change arguments passed to someUsefulThing, there's a chance that one forgets to do so in all calls"?  What?  How is that "awful"?  That's a trivial consequence of referencing a function more than once.    I'm failing to understand what you're talking about and how function reference is "awful" since it's inescapable.

Comment: See the accepted answer. The result expression {'message': 'Hello, ' + name + '!'} is written once for all presentations.

Comment: @temoto: what?  I can't understand your point.  How is referencing a function more than once "awful".  The code written "once and for all" uses the `+` function two times.  Isn't that just as "awful" as using `someUsefulThing` two times?  I cannot understand what distinction you are making.  Can you clarify, please?

Comment: Your htmlView and jsonView functions serve different representations for same data, right? So `someUsefulThing(request, object_id)` is a data retrieval expression. Now you have two copies of same expression in different points in your program. In the accepted answer, the data expression is written once. Replace your `someUsefulThing` call with a long string, like `paginate(request, Post.objects.filter(deleted=False, owner=request.user).order_by('comment_count'))` and look at the code. I hope it will illustrate my point.

Comment: @temoto: I guess you object to referencing some functions more than once.  I can't understand that.  Somehow `someUsefulThing` has a special status what `+` does not have.  This appears to be based on the length of the name or the number of arguments or some other criteria which I can't discern.

Comment: Did you try to write that long expression? (twice in sibling functions) ?

Comment: @temoto: Using a function more than once means that sometimes, the name of the function (however long) must get repeated.  That's basically how function references work.  The name gets repeated.  As I showed in my answer, two places can reference a function and the name will get repeated.  I understand that you object to this, but my example shows repeating a long expression.  I can't find a problem with it because I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Okay, i guess it needs paper and visual contact to explain my point.

Comment: @temoto: All it needs is a clear definition of why function references are so evil.  `someUsefulThing` cannot be used twice.  `+` can be used twice.  Please provide some distinction that allows be to determine what functions can be used twice and what functions can't be used twice.  If it's so complex that it can't be defined in a sentence, then post it to your blog.

Comment: You keep repeating that it's about function references. I keep repeating that it's not. Yes, many function references is fine (like we use `unicode` and `min` so many times, it's fine). Many duplicate expressions is not (like repeating `"debug: " + str(this)`, this is evil). Do you understand difference between `str` and `"debug: " + str(foo)` ?

Comment: @temoto: "Do you understand difference between str and "debug: " + str(foo) ?"  Apparently not.  Somehow one expression is bad and one expression is good.  I cannot see what rule or metric or principle separates one from the other.  They're expressions.  One expression is acceptable to you and one is not acceptable to you.  I cannot discern how you are making this decision.  I cannot parse any rule -- it appears like a random decision to me.  Please provide a clear definition that I can use without resorting to asking you which is better.

Comment: `str` does not evaluate to useful expression. `str(arguments)` does. In some other language (i.e. C or Java) the former would not even be an expression.

Answer (score 11):

See [Python Web Frameworks](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) wiki.

You probably do not need the *full stack* frameworks, but the remaining list is still quite long.

Answer (score 8):

I really like [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/).  Here's an example of a restful web service:

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy import expose

class Converter:
    @expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

    @expose
    def fahr_to_celc(self, degrees):
        temp = (float(degrees) - 32) * 5 / 9
        return "%.01f" % temp

    @expose
    def celc_to_fahr(self, degrees):
        temp = float(degrees) * 9 / 5 + 32
        return "%.01f" % temp

cherrypy.quickstart(Converter())
```

This emphasizes what I really like about CherryPy; this is a completely working example that's very understandable even to someone who doesn't know the framework.  If you run this code, then you can immediately see the results in your web browser; e.g. visiting http://localhost:8080/celc_to_fahr?degrees=50 will display `122.0` in your web browser.

Comment: That's a nice example, but there's nothing RESTful about it.

Comment: @Wahnfrieden: Could you help the rest of us out by clarifying why you do not think the above is RESTful? From my point of view, it looks like a classic example of REST and doesn't appear to break any of the rules or constraints of a RESTful system.

Comment: In simple terms, what the CherryPy example above is doing is exposing methods as "HTTP callable" remote procedures. That's RPC. It's entirely "verb" oriented.

RESTful architectures focus on the *resources* managed by a server and then offer a very *limited* set of operations on those resources: specifically, POST (create), GET (read), PUT (update) and DELETE (delete). The manipulation of these resources, in particular changing their *state* via PUT, is the key pathway whereby "stuff happens".

Comment: You can write more RESTfull APIs using CherryPy http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/REST.html

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at

- [Itty](http://github.com/toastdriven/itty/tree) ([blog post](http://www.toastdriven.com/fresh/itty-sinatra-inspired-micro-framework/))
- [Bottle](http://github.com/defnull/bottle/tree)
- [web.py](http://webpy.org/)
- [juno](http://brianreily.com/project/juno/)

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any reason to use Django just to expose a REST api, there are lighter and more flexible solutions. Django carries a lot of other things to the table, that are not always needed. For sure not needed if you only want to expose some code as a REST service.

My personal experience, fwiw, is that once you have a one-size-fits-all framework, you'll start to use its ORM, its plugins, etc. just because it's easy, and in no time you end up having a dependency that is very hard to get rid of.

Choosing a web framework is a tough decision, and I would avoid picking a full stack solution just to expose a REST api.

Now, if you really need/want to use Django, then Piston is a nice REST framework for django apps.

That being said, CherryPy looks really nice too, but seems more RPC than REST.

Looking at the samples (I never used it), probably web.py is the best and cleanest if you only need REST.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a discussion in CherryPy docs on REST: http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/progguide/REST.html

In particular it mentions a built in CherryPy dispatcher called MethodDispatcher, which invokes methods based on their HTTP-verb identifiers (GET, POST, etc...).

Answer (score 6):

In 2010, the Pylons and repoze.bfg communities "joined forces" to create [Pyramid](http://pylonsproject.org/), a web framework based most heavily on repoze.bfg. It retains the philosophies of its parent frameworks, and can be used for [RESTful services](http://zhuoqiang.me/a/restful-pyramid).  It's worth a look.

Comment: With Pyramid you can make use of [Cornice](http://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), which provides useful helpers for building and documenting REST web services.

Answer (score 5):

[Piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) is very flexible framework for wirting RESTful APIs for Django applications.

Answer (score 5):

Seems all kinds of python web frameworks can implement RESTful interfaces now.

For Django, besides tastypie and piston, django-rest-framework is a promising one worth to mention. I've already migrated one of my project on it smoothly.

> Django REST framework is a lightweight REST framework for Django, that
>   aims to make it easy to build well-connected, self-describing RESTful
>   Web APIs.

Quick example:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from djangorestframework.resources import ModelResource
from djangorestframework.views import ListOrCreateModelView, InstanceModelView
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyResource(ModelResource):
    model = MyModel

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ListOrCreateModelView.as_view(resource=MyResource)),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', InstanceModelView.as_view(resource=MyResource)),
)
```

Take the example from official site, all above codes provide api, self explained document(like soap based webservice) and even sandbox to test a bit. Very convenience.

Links:
http://django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Especially the browesable interface is saving a lot of time while developing! Many other advantages, so everyone starting rest implementation should have a look. I started with tastypie, but switched completely to django-rest-framework

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert on the python world but I have been using [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) which is an excellent web framework and can be used to create a restful framework.

Answer (score 3):

[web2py](http://www.web2py.com) includes support for easily building RESTful API's, described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10#Restful-Web-Services) and [here](http://vimeo.com/21133657) (video). In particular, look at [`parse_as_rest`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10#parse_as_rest-%28experimental%29), which lets you define URL patterns that map request args to database queries; and [`smart_query`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10#smart_query-%28experimental%29), which enables you to pass arbitrary natural language queries in the URL.

Comment: The links mentioned are no longer available

Comment: The links have been updated - try again.

Answer (score 2):

I you are using Django then you can consider [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) as an alternative to [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home). It is easier to tune to non-ORM data sources than piston, and has great [documentation](http://tastypieapi.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend TurboGears or Bottle:

TurboGears:

- less verbose than django
- more flexible, less HTML-oriented
- but: less famous

Bottle:

- very fast
- very easy to learn
- but: minimalistic and not mature

Answer (score 0):

We are working on a framework for strict REST services, check out http://prestans.googlecode.com

Its in early Alpha at the moment, we are testing against mod_wsgi and Google's AppEngine.

Looking for testers and feedback. Thanks.