# How to write a auto suggestion search in python?

Tags: jquery, python, search

How to write a database driven auto-suggestion search using python, mysql and jquery? Are there any relevant tutorials. Because Googling just gave me several results for PHP but not anything relevant to Python.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice jQuery plugin for this, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete.
To use your data with it, you need to write a controller in python that returns the autocomplete data as a JSON structure.

You also need to pick a good framework for writing the actual controller in, check this question for some good suggestions: [Recommendations of Python REST (web services) framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713847/recommendations-of-python-rest-web-services-framework)

Answer (score 2):

Auto complete is generally implemented in a similar manner to spell checkers.  Here's an article from [Nick's Blog about Levenshtein Autonoma](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata).  It's written in python so you can follow along.  I said generally before because while this will do spell checking and suggest similar names, it fails at anticipating where the popular queries are being done.  For that, a naive approach would be a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) where you've weighed the nodes based on the popularity of their search.