# how to use GWT for python app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gwt

I have developed my app using python in google app engine. Now I want to create GUI for my app and for that I want to use advantage of GWT.

So is it possible to use GWT with python app?

If yes then which is easiest way because I have seen pyjamas but I need other then that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not just out of the box, but have you had a look at [gwt-python-rpc](http://code.google.com/p/python-gwt-rpc/)? Have a look and let me know if that gives you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a REST/JSON service in Python: [Recommendations of Python REST (web services) framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713847/recommendations-of-python-rest-web-services-framework)

Then consume this service with GWT (points 2, 3, and 4): http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html

Comment: in the end gwt is just javascript after all. :)