# python RESTful webservice framework: roll my own or is there a recommended library?

Tags: python, web-services, rest, frameworks

I need to write a python webservice, but I would rather use a LIGHT WEIGHT framework (no one mention Django please), so that I can cater for more complicated scenarios in the future.

Is there a (peer) recommended library that I can use or at least can provide a good starting point?

[Edit]

To clarify, I am talking about a RESTful web service here - nothing to do with SOAP and/or WSDL

Comment: Looks like someone already asked this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713847/recommendations-of-python-rest-web-services-framework

Comment: That was a long time ago.  Pyramid didn't even exist.  Is there a statute of limitations on duplicates?

Comment: no statute of limitations; the original should be updated with current information. In a perfect world there should be only one page for each question to prevent knowledge-seekers from having to visit several different questions that address the same general topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommendations of Python REST (web services) framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713847/recommendations-of-python-rest-web-services-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you look at Cherry Py.  http://cherrypy.org/

Comment: Looks like there are quite a few good frameworks out there. I'm settling for Cherry partly because its been around a lot longer than the others and (I'm hoping), it is more likely to have been used in anger + prob a greater pool of users to tap into ...

Answer (score 6):

Try [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/), which is the result of a merger between the Pylons and repoze.bfg frameworks. It's relatively lightweight, yet robust and well-documented.

For RESTful services in Pyramid, you might find [this blog post](http://zhuoqiang.me/a/restful-pyramid) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation looking for lightweight, and tired of Django.  I came across web.py, which seems to be as lightweight as it can get.

web.py main site: http://webpy.org/
web.py github: https://github.com/webpy/webpy

Comment: I'm using web.py for a RESTful webapp I'm writing. I'm sure Pyramid or Flask might be better frameworks - but given limited resources I've found web.py to be extremely easy.

Answer (score 0):

[web2py](http://www.web2py.com) may be of interest. It includes support for [web services](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/09) and has recently added RESTful API functionality, described [here](http://vimeo.com/21133657) (video) and [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/g5hxq/web2py_trunk_has_a_new_restful_api_that_writes_db/c1l2ykg). If you have any questions, ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Answer (score 0):

[Eve](http://python-eve.org) is an open source Python REST API Framework powered by Flask, MongoDB and Redis. It allows you to effortlessly build and deploy highly customizable, fully featured RESTful Web Services.

[disclaimer: I am the project author]