# Python RESTfull Server

Tags: python, windows, rest

I am new in python and I have to run a project about web services with the following specs:

1. Windows Server (2003/2008)
2. REST architecture enabled
3. Python platform (any version)

My questions are:

1. Which web server fits better (IIS, Apache, ...)?
2. May I use GoogleAppEngine for commercial purposes?
3. In order to make RESTful web services on windows which python modules I will have to have?
4. Does anyone have a better architecture in his mind about these specs?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: "May I use GoogleAppEngine for commercial purposes?"  You should ask Google.  Not random strangers.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713847/recommendations-of-python-rest-web-services-framework ?

Comment: BrainStorm I have seen this post. I'm trying to find a solution on Windows OS.

Comment: @user730153: "I'm trying to find a solution on Windows OS"?  What's wrong with the answers to the other question?  Specifically.  What's not Windows about those answers?

Answer (score 1):

> Which web server fits better (IIS, Apache, ...)?

Fits what better?  Fits Windows?  Fits RESTful web services?

It doesn't much matter.  Which ever one you can configure and manage.

> In order to make RESTful web services on windows which python modules I will have to have?

All of them.

REST is simply a small extension to HTTP.  Any web server and web framework can do it.

Many of us use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Piston](https://www.djangoproject.com/).  Some use [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/).

Google "Django REST" or "Python REST" and you'll find a real lot of great alternatives.

> Does anyone have a better architecture in his mind about these specs?

Since this is so vague, it's not possible to have a "better" architecture.  Details would be required so suggest any improvements.

Comment: Forgive me if this heard as foolish. Is Django available on windows? I have tried to download it and has only *nix sources!

Comment: "and has only *nix sources"?  What does that mean? What have you seen that indicates it "has only *nix sources"?  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I mean source code. In download area I would except to find a windows installer package or something similar!!

Comment: @user730153: "I would except to find a windows installer package or something similar"?  Why?  Why do you expect this?  Python doesn't need such foolishness.  Please actually **read** the Django documentation.  Also, please actually **do** a Python tutorial or two.  Windows installers for Python packages are very, very rare.  We avoid them if possible.  Why do you expect something that's such a bad idea?

Comment: Sorry S.Lott, As you can see I need your help!!! Since now I wrote code only in .NET! Python it's not my choice. So I think I must install first a unix shell on my windows server. Is this correct?

Comment: _If you're using Linux, Mac OS X or some other flavor of Unix, enter the command sudo python setup.py install at the shell prompt. If you're using Windows, start up a command shell with administrator privileges and run the command setup.py install._

Comment: S.Lott you're right. I'm clueless. Don't get angry, however. I'm sorry for your wasted time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user730153: "So I think I must install first a unix shell on my windows server"?  No.  Why would you do such a thing?  "If you're using Linux..."  Stop reading at that word: "Linux".  "If you're using Windows, start up a command shell".  That's the `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: @user730153: Please (1) SEARCH on Stack Overflow for answers to each of these more specific questions about "installers" (whatever they are), Windows, Command Shells, etc.  Your questions have ALL been asked. really.  Then (2) only if search has zero results, then ask your more specific question as a more specific question.  Not another comment on this question, but a new question.

Answer (score 1):

1. [uWSGI on nginx](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/RunOnNginx).
2. Yes, just enable billing and set a budget.
3. A lot of people like [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) for RESTful services.
4. Not unless you provide a list of requirements, there is way too many options.