# How do I get JSON data from RESTful service using Python?

Tags: python, json, rest, kerberos

Is there any standard way of getting JSON data from RESTful service using Python?

I need to use kerberos for authentication.

some snippet would help.

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713847/recommendations-of-python-rest-web-services-framework

Comment: I'm not looking fro " Python-**based** REST frameworks". I want to use RESTful service provided by some java server in python. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Something like this should work unless I'm missing the point:

```
import json
import urllib2
json.load(urllib2.urlopen("url"))
```

Comment: this would work if there are no credential required to pass. But I get this "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized" error

Comment: Where are you trying to download from?

Comment: I need to use Kerberos authentication. Sorry, I forgot to mention in question.

Comment: @BalamuruganK what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using unix. trying with kerberos
 lib to get token to pass it to httpConnection.putheader('Authorization', ?)

Comment: @BalamuruganK I won't really be able to help you until I get to my linux box tomorrow. I'm on a PC and I can't try it out now. Sorry! But if I remember correctly, urllib2 has an addheaders() method that might help you too. I'll check back tomorrow to see how you did. I would still recommend you to edit and improve your question with more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but urllib2 does not look as nice as the requests library, at a glance.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant I wanted to give another choice other than what [Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7750945/463065) suggested. It seemed to have fitted the OPs need since it's the accepted answer but I agree if might not be the best solution for all cases.

Comment: When Python 3 instead of 'urllib2' use 'urllib.request'

Answer (score 127):

I would give the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library a try for this. Essentially just a much easier to use wrapper around the standard library modules (i.e. urllib2, httplib2, etc.) you would use for the same thing. For example, to fetch json data from a url that requires basic authentication would look like this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://thedataishere.com',
                         auth=('user', 'password'))
data = response.json()
```

For kerberos authentication the [requests project](https://github.com/requests) has the [reqests-kerberos](https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos) library which provides a kerberos authentication class that you can use with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org):

```
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth

response = requests.get('http://thedataishere.com',
                         auth=HTTPKerberosAuth())
data = response.json()
```

Comment: If you're missing the `requests` module, simply do: `pip install requests`. More info and docs [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/)

Comment: here why my json response become with u before the key, value pair?         *{u'status': u'FINISHED', u'startTime': u'2016-11-08T15:32:33.241Z', u'jobId': u'f9d71eaa-d439-4a39-a258-54220b14f1b8', u'context': u'sql-context', u'duration': u'0.061 secs'}*

Answer (score 27):

You basically need to make a HTTP request to the service, and then parse the body of the response. I like to use httplib2 for it:

```
import httplib2 as http
import json

try:
    from urlparse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
}

uri = 'http://yourservice.com'
path = '/path/to/resource/'

target = urlparse(uri+path)
method = 'GET'
body = ''

h = http.Http()

# If you need authentication some example:
if auth:
    h.add_credentials(auth.user, auth.password)

response, content = h.request(
        target.geturl(),
        method,
        body,
        headers)

# assume that content is a json reply
# parse content with the json module
data = json.loads(content)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you desire to use Python 3, you can use the following:

```
import json
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request('url')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    result = json.loads(response.readall().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: How does this use kerberos for authentication?

Answer (score 3):

Well first of all I think rolling out your own solution for this all you need is urllib2 or httplib2 . Anyways in case you do require a generic REST client check this out .

https://github.com/scastillo/siesta

However i think the feature set of the library will not work for most web services because they shall probably using oauth etc .. . Also I don't like the fact that it is written over httplib which is a pain as compared to httplib2 still should work for you if you don't have to handle a lot of redirections etc ..