# Getting started with API in django

Tags: python, json, django, api

I am confused as to how APIs work with django in general. I am looking to get started but am a bit confused where to start. I am fairly new to django but have mastered most of the basics.

I am looking to understand how to communicate with other REST apis, how to send and receive json data, what is needed for this data(where does it live, are models required?, do I create views to access json data?)

I am looking for a comprehensive tutorial or book/article that I can follow that will teach me the ins and outs of this. Any help on where to get started would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Django is for web development.  If what you want to do is get JSON from some remote RESTful service, no part of that requires Django.  Instead, try urllib or httplib2, and [check simple examples elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750557/how-do-i-get-json-data-from-restful-service-using-python).

Again, sending JSON data is a simple as using the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library in python, and using the same urllib tricks you use to consume JSON from other people.  So no django needed there either.

As for whether models are required, well that depends 100% on what you're trying to do.   Your question about needing "views" on json data I think confuses several different issues.

I'd recommend you read up on RESTful services in general, and where JSON fits before you start implementation.