# Calling Rest Service in Python - without name value pairs

Tags: python, rest, service

I need to call a WCF Rest Service passing JSON.    The problem I can't figure out is I don't have name value pairs.  I need to pass something like this (this is in SoapUI):

["SB2011-037","SB2013-028"]

I have been trying to use URLEncode and I am guessing that is not the way to go.  I have also seen some stuff with urllib.quote but that doesn't seem right.

```
url = "http://server/testService/Services/Posse.svc/rest/GetDataByProjectNumbers"
values = urllib.urlencode({
    '': 'SB2013-028',
    '': 'SB2011-037',
        })
#data = urllib.urlencode(values)
request = urllib2.Request(url,data)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Have tried a couple of things I have seen.

```
values = {["SB2011-037","SB2013-028"]}

values = urllib.urlencode({
    None: 'SB2013-028',
    None: 'SB2011-037',
        }) 

values = urllib.urlencode({
    '': 'SB2013-028',
    '': 'SB2011-037',
        })
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: seems like it's a matter of how your Rest Service is designed, I would think a name like 'GetDataByProjectNumber' would not accept a list of multiple numbers.. have you tried this: http://server/testService/Services/Posse.svc/rest/GetDataByProjectNumbers/SB2013-028/  Also your first example with urlib2 using the data parameter is actually sending a post request which is probably not what you want. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7750946/471339

Comment: I would like to use a post because it is potentially sending a large amount of data.   I would consider using SOAP, not sure how to begin there.   It does accept JSON and can comfirm with SoapUI and get to work.  For example in SoapUI I can pass this ["SB2011-037","SB2013-028"]  and it works fine.