# RESTful Python for Java (Jersey) developer

Tags: java, rest, python-2.7, jersey

BACKGROUND:

I have a REST API implemented in Java using Jersey. My API uses four verbs: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. 
I find developing REST APIs in java very easy and straight forward.

eg here is an elaborate `hello` webservice (I say elaborate because there are easier ways, but this is more representative):

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource{

   @GET
   @Path("name/{name}")
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
   public Response sayHello(@PathParam("name") String name){
       return Response.ok("Hello "+name).build();
   }
}
```

PROBLEM:

I am learning python. I want to convert my Java Jersey REST API into python.

Basically Jersey is Java's implementation of REST (aka JAX-RS: Java API for RESTful Web Services). Does python have a reference implementation of REST? If not, is there any implementation out there that comes close and would be easy to use for someone coming from Java-Jersey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check the previous similar question: [Recommendations of Python REST (web services) framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713847/recommendations-of-python-rest-web-services-framework)

Python does not have a built-in REST framework, but I personally have had good experiences with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).

It's very similar in use to Jersey (Bottle example):

```
@route('/')
@route('/hello/<name>')
def greet(name='Stranger'):
    return template('Hello {{name}}, how are you?', name=name)
```

Handling HTTP verbs:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        do_the_login()
    else:
        show_the_login_form()
```

Comment: So there seems to exist no REST implementation in python. Thanks for the link and the example.