# Python micro-framework for RESTful applications?

Tags: python, json, rest, web-frameworks, stateless

Previously I have been using [web2py](http://www.web2py.com), it's quite good but a little heavy for my purposes.

Basically I am seeking a Python microframework with:

- Automatic no-arg function -> controller (endpoint) conversion (or simple `@app.route()` style syntax)
- Ability to expose (send/receive) these endpoints as JSON; and restrict their access by HTTP verb (e.g.: only GET); at the [controller] function level
- Automated error/exception capturing (with tracebacks)
- Deployability to heroku and OpenShift

Thinking [wheezy.web](https://bitbucket.org/akorn/wheezy.web), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org), [bottle](http://bottlepy.org) or [pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org)…

From an MVC standpoint, all I require are the Models (db+schema) and Controllers (managing HTTP verbs + endpoints + connection to/from Models).

Comment: I'd go with Flask (I'm a bit biased, though). Check this extension → [Flask-RESTful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks, will definitely benchmark my dev time with it. FYI for mods: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/713847/587021) was closed and all the answers are out-dated; so maybe we can keep this thread open?

Comment: FYI: For anyone still looking at this thread, I have been using [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org) for months now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [python frameworks](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks). Try to use Grok or TurboGears.

Comment: Isn't grok one of the heaviest frameworks because of zope?